# Angular ReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, routes, save

Recently I created Custom Reuse Strategy to reuse components for saving user inputs that is not saved properly(navigating away without clicking save button).
       
        `shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
        if ((<any>route.component).name == "PersonDetailEditComponent" )
            return true;
        }
        store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void 
       {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
       }`
Now all inputs on person detail is being saved whenever user navigates away from component. However, I do not need save component when user clicks save button.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to access component from CustomRouteStrategy, like 
`route.component.isPersonSaved`. The problem is that I do not know how to cast `route.component` to `PersonDetailEditComponent`. 
Does it even correct way to accomplish such behavior? Any good practices?

Comment: `component` is component class. The instance cannot be accessed in `route`, at least naturally. The interaction between app units is performed via common services, use that. You could make `handlers` a service or else. Component instance has been already stored in `handlers`, so you can check it there, but I don't think that it would be a good way to handle this.

Comment: @estus Thanks. So do you mean use custom service, that will injected in ReuseStrategy and component class? To be honest, I had that idea, but I thought there should be easier way

Comment: Well, an easier way would be something like `this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path].componentRef.instance.isSaved`, but it doesn't smell very good. Probably something should be done in CanDeactivate to improve interaction between a component and a strategy.

Comment: @estus I think you are right. Seems better to use Guards and Service to handle unsaved state, because we have reference to component using CanActivate, CanDeactivate